# write_file not working in code igniter

Tags: codeigniter

**iam trying to file writing using following code is not done**

```
 public function __construct()
    {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->helper('url');
            $this->load->helper('file');
    }    
    public function index()
    {           
      $data = "Some file data";                     
        if (!write_file(base_url()."test.txt", $data))
        {
                echo 'Unable to write the file';
        }
        else
        {
                echo 'File written!';                          
        }
    }
```

**After i changed the code its done**

```
public function __construct()
    {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->helper('url');
            $this->load->helper('file');
    }    
    public function index()
    {           
      $data = "Some file data";                     
        if (!write_file('M:\xampp\htdocs\tt\text.txt', $data))
        {
                echo 'Unable to write the file';
        }
        else
        {
                echo 'File written!';                           
        }
    }
```

**Any one can explain what is the problem in above code**

Comment: When you are working with files, you must use absolute or relative path of file in system. URL can't achieve that need because it would be insecure in way anybody could change your files through URLs. Only one that have permission to manage files should have ability to work with files and that is why you have to use file path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When creating a file with write_file make sure your folder/directory is there where you would like to create file

Then I would recommend using FCPATH

```
$data = "Some file data"; 

if (write_file(FCPATH . '/document/text.txt', $data) == FALSE)
{
   echo 'Unable to write the file';

} else {
    echo 'File written!';                           
}
```

My directory

```
application

document

system

index.php
```